# Cypress giving error about promise while sending api request

Tags: javascript, selenium, automation, promise, cypress

I got a promise error by cypress; what should I do? What am I missing?

```
let woID = 0
let woCoordinate = 0
let keyCloakToken = 0

class utils {
 createIncidentViaAPI() {

        keyCloakToken = localStorage.getItem('keycloak-token')
        fetch('https://URL', {
            headers: {
                accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
                authorization: 'Bearer ' + keyCloakToken,
                'content-type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
            },
            body: '{"description":"keycloak","type":"SY","startDate":"2022-08-14T12:19:00.000Z","locationAddress":"Japanese Pagoda Ohio Dr SW","latitude":38.88366120709875,"longitude":-77.04149404953358,"sourceType":"CALL"}',
            method: 'POST'
        })
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then((out) => {
                cy.log(out.data.incidentId)
            })
    }
```

the fetch request that you can see at the top is working stable without problem but I having some issues to work API request at the bottom.

the important thing is that when I send createWorkOrderViaAPI() request I should have to wait 60-70 seconds because the system responds every 60 secs. That's why I tried to use then block. by the way, I tried some different options too but I didn't solve the promise problem.

```
     createWorkOrderViaAPI() {
        cy.request({
            url: 'URL',
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                properties: 'wonum',    
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                MAXAUTH: 'autpassword',
                Authorization: 'Basic ' + 'autpassword'
            },
            body: {
                description: 'test request',
            }
        }).then((res) => {
            woID = res.body.wonum  
//here i want get some numbers then i want to use these second API request which you can see //inside then block.
        }).then((out)=>{
            fetch('https://URL', {
                headers: {
                    accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
                    'accept-language': 'tr-TR,tr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
                    authorization: 'Bearer ' + keyCloakToken,
                    
                },
                body:
                    '{"statusList":"sortDirection":"DESC","archivalTypeList":["ACTIVE"],"countByField":"NEIGHBORHOOD","searchText":"' +
            ---> i want use  woID number here ---> woID +
                    '}',
                method: 'POST'
            }).then((res) => {
                woCoordinate = res.body.wkt
                cy.log(woCoordinate)
            })
        })
    }
```

when I run this code i getting error message by cypress about promise I leaving the message doc here
especially when I change cy.request to fetch error just disappears but fetch is not working not creating order as i want.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Still I didn't find a clear solution.

Comment: It looks like it is complaining about the line `cy.log(woCoordinate)`? What happens if you replace it with `console.log(woCoordinate)`?

Comment: Hello, I tried that even more I just deleted all of the other cy. codes inside of code but still gives the same error. I think it is about requests.

Comment: So it must be some other `cy.log()` but I can't see any other.

Comment: because there is no other this error message screen is always changing sometimes giving cy.request error some times this screen that you seeing here. I sent here full class, other class that I using for just launch for the target page.

Answer (score -2):

The problem is that you cant use `cy.` methods inside of any `then` block.

```
.then(()=>{
don't use here any cypress method
})
```

I separated my own API requests and deleted necessary cypress requests then it worked.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).